# Making UIImageView full screen on .xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, interface-builder, xib

I'm trying to implement a "Launch Screen" .xib so that my app will get "This app is optimized for the iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus" denotation in the app store.

So I create a new Launch Screen .xib template, delete the included label, drop a `UIImageView` onto it, I push the pin button and I set all the "spacing to the nearest neighbor" constraints to 0, I set the `UIImageView` to aspect fit, and have it point to one of my asset catalogs.

When I run the app on my phone, I'm getting some very weird results as far as the positioning of the `UIImageView` and the size of the image in it (it definitely isn't filling out the screen with the image). Does anyone have anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Differentiate between the image view and the image. Give the image view a distinctive background color (e.g. red) so you can see what is really happening.

Comment: Well, aspect fit doesn't mean "fill out the screen with the image", so your expectations/desires do not match what you are doing. If you want to "fill out the screen" you would need to say aspect _fill_. That is what my answer below is hinting at: content mode means something here.

Comment: You are still not really giving details, though. Consider doing what I've suggested: make the image view background red so you can see where it really is, and howzabout posting an image of what is happening? And maybe an image of the constraints?

Comment: @matt - Sorry forgot to mention I did try your suggestion of changing the background color and it appears the image is definitely filling out the full area of the UIImageView because I don't see any of the color I specified. Also, I did try aspect fill and same result, shouldn't matter anyway as I have separate launch images for each screen size that are sized to fit the screen. I will try to get some images up, thanks again for the help.

Comment: Or even post it a sample project at github! I'd be glad to take a look and try to tweak it for you.

Comment: "the image is definitely filling out the full area of the UIImageView" But then that is a Major Clue! If you don't see any red (or whatever) but the image is not filling the screen, that suggests your constraints are wrong, doesn't it? Because if your constraints were right, the image view would fill the screen and therefore so would the image. Do you see? That is what my second bullet point in my answer below is trying to tell you...

Comment: @matt - You're too kind. Thanks going to throw that together right now.

Comment: @matt - Yeah, based on other answers I've read here, they just told me to set all of the "spacing to the nearest neighbor" constraints to 0. If you were going about trying to make a UIImageView that filled out the full screen for each different screen type, how would you go about doing that? I do everything in code so haven't worked with interface builder in years, and everything I try seems to fail LOL.

Comment: I really have no idea about the nearest neighbor. You have no nearest neighbor. That sounds bogus to me. It is the _superview_ you want to be pinned to, obviously. Just do in the nib exactly what you would do in code.

Comment: And of course on iOS 8 you need to be careful about pinning to the superview because of the new margins. Make sure you are pinned to the _edges_ not the margins.

Comment: @matt - thanks for your help, I ended up figuring out what my problem was. Listed it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem I was having was I trying to link the LaunchScreen.xib to a LaunchImage asset catalog. This will not work, you have to link it to a normal image asset catalog and use the universal image grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any actual details of what you are doing, so one has to guess. There are, however, two things to keep in mind here:

- Where the image is shown doesn't really have all that much to do with the position/size of the image view. It has *something* to do with it, but the most important thing is actually the Content Mode of the image view.
- Image views under auto layout are tricky, because they are resized based on the image - unless your constraints *completely* determine the height and width of the image view in some other way. In all probability your constraints are not doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the lack of information. I've updated the post to include some new stuff.